# Very strange behavior with if data-bind and file upload

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I noticed some very strange things happening on a page that I use knockout to power. Here's the situation:

```html
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="">Upload Document</h3>
        <form id="document-form">
            <span class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="files" value="Upload" multiple="" id="input-file" style="display: none;" data-bind="event:{change: uploadFiles}" />
                <label for="input-file" class="btn btn-default">Select Files</label>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This little area would immediately post the file back to my server whenever the user added files. The code for uploadFiles looked like this.

```
    //formNode is passed into the viewmodel at time of instantiation, and it is just
    //the DOM node that represents that <form></form> element
    self.uploadFiles = function() {
        self.showLoading(true);
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(formNode)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: someFunction
        });
    };
```

So this worked very well. Then, I added an if data-bind to the whole thing like so:

```html
    <div class="col-md-4" data-bind="if: userHasPermission">
        <h3 class="">Upload Document</h3>
        <form id="document-form">
            <span class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="files" value="Upload" multiple="" id="input-file" style="display: none;" data-bind="event:{change: uploadFiles}" />
                <label for="input-file" class="btn btn-default">Select Files</label>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Now the user (assuming they have permission) can see the upload form and can also choose a file to upload, but the uploadFiles function now materializes nothing in the formData variable and consequently, nothing but an empty, nameless file gets posted back to the server.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there something I can do to mitigate this?

Comment: You don't happen to have several forms,  i.e. $(formNode) returns more then 1 form element?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.

Comment: Sorry for the blunt questions, but do you get the same behaviour if you put the if-binding in a virtual element?

Comment: I tried, and in fact it still exhibits the same behavior! Very weird.

Comment: You know what, though, when I changed the if binding to visible, that fixed my problem. Very strange indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that formNode does not exist at "instantiation" when you use the if: binding. The html in the if: binding block is not generated by knockout until userHasPermission is true. If the userHasPermission is changed to false, then the HTML is removed from the DOM.

With the visible binding, the html is there, just hidden.

So, to fix this, you can continue to use the visible binding as you noted in your comment or you can simply change your upload files function to get the DOM element each time:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#document-form')[0]);
```

or whatever the form ID is.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I like to avoid querying the DOM inside of my viewmodel, so I don't want to go with your proposed solution, however using the visible binding solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also I don't think you're entirely accurate with your assesment of the node not existing. When I put a breakpoint on the line that uses the formNode variable and hover over formNode I can very clearly see the element is there, without changing to the code you put. I guess it's technically "there" before I call make my vm and before I call ko.applyBindings, but AFTER I call ko.applyBindings it removes it and re-insterts it into the DOM depending on the value of userHasPermission?

Comment: Well technically, the formNode you want doesn't exist yet. It depends on when you call applyBindings in relation to saving a reference to formNode. I made an assumption since I couldn't see your code. I should have said "may not exist." But the behavior of knockout I described is correct. Either way, you can't rely on a saved ref to formNode as knockout will add and remove that section of the DOM within an if: binding and your reference would not be valid.

Comment: Just curious, what is the value of userHasPermission when you applyBindings? If it is false initially, then the node will def. be removed then added again when it changes to true.

Comment: It is in fact false :)

Answer (score 0):

Come to think of it, even though you already solved it. But the if binding physically removes the element. So the form element you pass at instantiation doesn't exist anymore.